# How to show the contents hidden by keyboard in the webview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

My android application is a webview, and in first page there are 5 editboxes. When i enter some data in editbox the last editbox is hidden by keyboard. So i enclosed webview within a scrollview. But the scrolling is happening only on the first page but not on all the other pages. Is it possible to scroll screen up only if keyboard is hiding some text in webview?

Meanwhile i tried using the window attribute windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" but still i am getting the same problem. Any Ideas on how to make this working?

-Regards,
Ron..

Answer (score 0):

This could be the consequence of http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497. Looks like adjustResize should work if you created your layout correctly, but it will not if your app is in fullscreen mode (i.e. the Android status bar is not displayed). If your app runs in fullscreen mode, try the 'normal' mode for a change and see if the webview adjusts its size correctly when the keyboard is displayed.